# How to deserialize a list of lists?

Tags: java, jackson

I have a list of lists `"[[2,3,5,7],[1,4,6]]"`

How can I convert it into a Java `ArrayList` using Jackson? Any reference material or example will work.

Comment: Please show us what code you have tried.  What problem are you having with it?

Comment: Actually i don't have an idea how to tackle this so that is why i asked any reference will also work

Comment: I'm sure a Google search will help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the generics wrapper to deserialize using objectmapper,

```
public static <T> T fromJSON(final TypeReference<T> type,
      final String jsonPacket) {
   T data = null;

   try {
      data = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonPacket, type);
   } catch (Exception e) {
      // Handle the problem
   }
   return data;
```

Example

```
var list = "[[2,3,5,7],[1,4,6]]";
var result = JsonUtils.deserialize(new TypeReference<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>() {}, list);
```

Comment: Thank you @Nainesh Patel for the answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is some example code using `TypeFactory`

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        final TypeFactory typeFactory = TypeFactory.defaultInstance();
        final ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> data = new ObjectMapper().readValue("[[2,3,5,7],[1,4,6]]",
                typeFactory.constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class,
                        typeFactory.constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, Integer.class)));
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

It builds the object and prints

```
[[2, 3, 5, 7], [1, 4, 6]]
```